# Nix the reverse tag

Tags: discussion, support, tags, moderation

The [reverse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse) tag is very meta, covers several categories. I nominate it to go away.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse

Comment: I don't have enough rep to edit your post so I'll just mention that if you use `[tag:reverse]` in your post instead of just the backticks it shows like this: [tag:reverse]. It automatically becomes the link to the tag, so no need for the additional url.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would agree; many of the questions tagged would be covered by the `reverse-polarity`tag [latest questions tagged with reverse-polarity](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-polarity).

The first question in the latest for `reverse` is asking about a *reversing light circuit on a car*. How that adds any value to the question is beyond me.

The term reverse covers such a broad range that a proper definition would appear to be impossible and that being the case it adds no value (but does clutter the tags with a meaningless entry from my perspective)